# How to randomly add data from a database to a button's text attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, webforms

I'm working on a project that is a quiz. I am using 4 asp buttons that are styled with CSS, and I am using those 4 buttons as answers, with the right or wrong answer in the button's text field. I have read around and found another post regarding something very similar to this but the answers were to use a dictionary list. I am kind of sure that I don't need to use a list, that I should be able to randomly assign the text attribute. Here is the code that I am using to add the answers to the buttons text attribute but I need to randomize where the answers go, because it wouldn't be right to have the correct answer in the same button all the time.

```
lblQuestion.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["Question"].ToString();
btn1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["CorrectAnswer"].ToString();
btn2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["WrongAnswer1"].ToString();
btn3.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["WrongAnswer2"].ToString();
btn4.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["WrongAnswer3"].ToString();
```

each button has an onlick method to change to the next question and changes the buttons text to the next answers. This code is in every buttonclick event...

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblQuestion.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["Question"].ToString();
    btn1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["CorrectAnswer"].ToString();
    btn2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["WrongAnswer1"].ToString();
    btn3.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["WrongAnswer2"].ToString();
    btn4.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["WrongAnswer3"].ToString();

    myNum = myNum + 1;
 }
```

I'm unsure but maybe I need to be able to use one method that can randomize all the buttons text instead of coding into each buttonclick event?

Thanks

Comment: here you need to write same code for all 4 buttons... then and only then you will be able to do that... but instead of using buttons, take 4 radio buttons and one submit button.. i think that will be easy task for you...

Comment: The reason why I chose a button is because its text is already centered and when the answer is selected it automatically moves onto the next question and set of answers, So I couldn't use a submit button. I could do the same with 4 radiobuttons, but between the two there shouldn't be much of a difference whether I'm setting the text of a radiobutton or a button. Either will do what I need, but its the matter of be able to randomly assign the correct answer and wrong answers to the text attribute. Unless I am missing something in your comment??

Comment: Yes, You can do it by radio chec as well and button as well, but here atleast you should have to give chance to quiz that by mistakely if he/she pressed wrong button then what will happen?? have you think upon that ??? JUst because of that i am telling to use radio button with a single button. That will be good idea.... Atleast give another chance to quiz take to think over his/her answer..

Comment: Yes I have thought about that, whether they select the correct answer or wrong answer the quiz moves along until the last question then it will display the results.

Comment: thats what i am saying buddy.... That's not good for ideal quiz.... alteast they should get atleast one change to think over their answer...

Comment: Its what my client requested. These quizzes are aimed towards ages 5 - 12, so the quizzes aren't difficult. I understand what you are saying, but I am agreeing with what was requested because I think the idea is good for the targeted age range. But now we're deviating from my question on how to randomly assign the answers to the text attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a simple subroutine to demonstrate how to randomly order strings and then attach them to buttons. This example simply demonstrates how to randomize the location of the correct answer among 4 possible places on the screen.

```
    static void Main()
    {

        // create array of 4 string (or answers in your case)
        //string[] array = new string[4] { "apple", "banana", "cranberry", "dragon fruit" };            
        string[] array = new string[4] {
            ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["CorrectAnswer"].ToString(),
            ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["WrongAnswer1"].ToString(),
            ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["WrongAnswer2"].ToString(),
            ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["WrongAnswer3"].ToString(),
        };

        // randomize the ordering of the items
        System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
        array = array.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();

        // each time you run this, the correct answer will be in a different place:
        btn1.Text = array[0];
        btn2.Text = array[1]; 
        btn3.Text = array[2];
        btn4.Text = array[3];

    }
```

Bonus answer, you can also wire-up multiple buttons to a single `Event Handler` like so. Once inside the handler, you can access the `Button` that raised the event and perform actions:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // attach event handlers
    Button1.Click += ButtonClick;
    Button2.Click += ButtonClick;
    Button3.Click += ButtonClick;
    Button4.Click += ButtonClick;
}

private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // your code here...

    // this is the button that raised the event
    Button button = (Button)sender;    
    // check its ID? you could also check its text, perform any actions you wish, etc.    
    if (button.ID == "Button1")
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Button 1 Clicked!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I see and understand what you are saying, just looking at how you did it looks to be the right way. Now with the array, how do I add the dataset? like this..
ds.Tables[0].Rows[myNum]["CorrectAnswer"].ToString();
etc...?

Comment: Edited the example to use your specific DataSource. You can get and add the strings any way you see fit, from a data table, from the database, etc.

Comment: Perfect!, this helps me out a huge amount.

Comment: I added additional code demonstrating how to wire up multiple buttons to a single handler to reduce your code.

Comment: When you attached the Button onclick event handlers to the new event ButtonClick, does the ButtonClick now replace all other buttons OnClick Event handlers?

Comment: No. The "plus equals" operator will add multiple event handlers to the same Click action so you may have more than one event firing if you are adding them elsewhere. The events will be raised in the order they are added. This was for demonstration purposes only because another user added a comment about it.

Comment: This is good to know, it really does cut down a lot of code now that I know about this, saves repeating myself. Perfect example of DRY